# Python: Making raw_input execute

Tags: python, raw-input

I'm fairly new to Python (I'm using Codecademy and am about 70% through,) and I'm wondering if it's possible for raw_input to run as an actual command. For instance, I thought I could use:

```
command = raw_input(">>>    ")
command
```

However, when I run it, it displays the >>> and allows me to type stuff, but the code I type won't run.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You may want to look into the [`code`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/code.html) module, which provides facilities for implementing REPLs like the Python interpreter does in interactive mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
command = raw_input(">>>    ")
exec(command)
```

but beware the user can execute ***anything***!

Answer (score 0):

When you were writing ">>>" in raw input, it was just the message content. In order to add it to the string and execute, do this:

```
import os

command = ">>>" + raw_input("") 
os.system(command)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `exec(command)` if you want to execute Python code.

Use `os.system(command)` if you want to execute commands of your operating system (like you would in the terminal)

Comment: Kind of off-topic, but I'm curious. Does that mean that if I download a Python script it could use os.system() to execute any command that doesn't require a password in my terminal without me knowing?
Ugh. Sucks to be a newbie.

Comment: @IanHuang, I never tried that but I think you would rather use `exec()` and you somehow have to load the file. Just try it with a simple python script :-)